# How to load home screen short cut icons using icon intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I am working on Launcher 3 for icon modification. I get the intent stored in local data base in this format.

```html
action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.android.settings/.Settings
```

now I want to know that how to recreate this icon using this intent

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly is this the intent that you looking for:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
```